# Remove 'index.php' from url without removing parameters in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, indexing, permanent

I have a condition for url redirect like,

> www.domain.com/something/anotherthing/index.php

i need the above url to redirect to

> www.domain.com/something/anotherthing/

If i go to

> www.domain.com/index.php/something/anotherthing

i want to redirect to

> www.domain.com/something/anotherthing

i have a redirect htaccess rule for this

> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index.php$1 [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^ /%1$1 [R=301,L]

But this works for the first condition but in the later it redirect me to the root page. Can anyone please help in this redirection.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index.php/?([^\ \?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

That should handle any location of `/index.php`.