# Removing index.php?p=page from URL - No redirect, No error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am having some trouble removing index.php?p=XXX from my URL's. Previously, if I were to navigate to a different page, I would go to mywebsite.com/index.php?p=about. I have added the following code to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This code works as expected, changing mywebsite.com/index.php?p=about to mywebsite.com/about, but my pages are not redirecting to the document at all. It changes the URL but doesn't redirect.

In my header file (for my navbar) I have the following:

```
<li><a href="index.php?p=about" class='active-page'>About</a></li>
```

I have tried changing that around but no luck as of yet...

Any ideas on what is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove 'index.php' from url without removing parameters in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393253/remove-index-php-from-url-without-removing-parameters-in-htaccess)